# Highlighting in vim: distinguish the lines with comment delimiter followed by special string

Tags: shell-script, shell, vim, syntax-highlighting

Highlighting in vim: distinguish the lines with comment delimiter followed by special string

In some cases, for example with the scripts for HPC clusters, when using SGE, TORQUE or Slurm we can have a shell script (like bash) with comment lines denoted by # but grid commands in lines with `#$`, `#PBS`, or `#SBATCH`.

What is an easy way to keep the same highlighting used for bash but excluding `#SomeString` from being considered a comment?

Comment: This question will probably get a more appropriate audience on Stack Overflow

Comment: If you're going to fob people off with other StackExchange WWW sites, at least fob people off with the vi one: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/  (-:

Comment: @glennjackman I am not sure if this is more for SO. It's not really about developing but about settings in vim.

Comment: Thanks @JdeBP, I didn't know that existed.

Comment: @myradio, it kind of is development: you're looking at updating an existing syntax file which is implemented in vimscript: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/sh.vim

Comment: Also, there's a specific tag for syntax files: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vim-syntax-highlighting/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by examining the definitions for comments in the shell syntax script:

```
:syn list shComment
--- Syntax items ---
shComment      xxx match /^\s*\zs#.*$/  contains=@shCommentGroup
                match /\s\zs#.*$/  contains=@shCommentGroup
                match /#.*$/  contained contains=@shCommentGroup
                links to Comment
```

#### Extend syntax cluster

There, you see what patterns for comments need to be overridden. But wait! That syntax script offers an extension mechanism via the [`:help :syn-cluster`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-cluster); the `contains=@shCommentGroup`

```
syn match shHPC "PBS" contained
```

That would highlight `PBS` *anywhere* inside a comment. If additional stuff can follow, append `.*$` to the pattern. If the `PBS` keyword must directly follow the `#`, add a *positive lookbehind assertion*:

```
syn match shHPC "#\@<=PBS" contained
```

You can all the other keywords via additional `:syn match` commands, or by using regular expression branches: `"#\@<=\(PBS\|SBATCH\|...\)"`.

Finally, that new syntax group has to be included in the syntax cluster for comments, and given a highlighting so you see it:

```
syn cluster shCommentGroup add=shHPC
hi link shHPC PreProc
```

#### Define overriding syntax match

Alternatively, you may want to skip the cluster and overwrite the comment syntax. For example, when the special keywords can only appear at the beginning of the line, but now after Bash commands. Or if you can't stand the fact that the cluster method will keep the `#` in the original highlighting.

```
syn match shHPC "^\s*\zs#PBS"
hi link shHPC PreProc
```

#### Activation

As these commands extend the built-in syntax, they need to be executed after them. The place for that is `~/.vim/after/syntax/sh.vim`. If you want to only conditionally activate them for certain projects, you can write a *filetype detection* that sets a marker variable, e.g. `b:is_HPC`, and then make the above code check that flag.